# QGIS 2.99 dev python import processing fails with ImportError

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, importerror

I've just installed one of the nightly build versions of QGIS 3.0 to have a play with, but on start-up, it's complaining that:

```
Python error: Couldn't load plugin 'processing' See message log (Python Error) for more details.
```

The full details from the log messages panel is like so:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 39, in <module>
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 45, in <module>
    from processing.script.ScriptUtils import ScriptUtils
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 34, in <module>
    from processing.script.ScriptAlgorithm import ScriptAlgorithm
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 40, in <module>
    from processing.core.GeoAlgorithm import GeoAlgorithm
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 51, in <module>
    from processing.algs.help import shortHelp
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins\processing\algs\help\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 647, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: bad magic number in 'yaml': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

My question is, is this maybe a problem with my installation (I installed through the [OSGeo4W](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#windows) setup tool, selected Advanced Install and chose qgis-dev with automatic installation of other dependencies), as in I missed something out? Or possibly there is some incompatibility issues as I still have QGIS 2.18 installed and it's not liking the fact that I'm mixing both versions?

Comment: I justed install QGIS 2.99 using OSGeo4W using the advanced install and selected qgis-dev, qgis-dev-pdb and qgis-full-dev and it works. But I uninstalled everything else before

Comment: I ran into the same problems with qgis-dev, and suspended it for the moment. There might still be unresolved issues in the porting from python 2 to python 3, maybe only Windows-related.

Comment: I'm starting to think it might have something to do with the yaml dependency, qgis 3 seems to be using the python 2 version of the library instead of python 3 :/

Answer (score 1):

Ended up doing a full uninstall of qgis-dev 2.99 and qgis 2.18 via OSGeo4W, making sure to remove those pyyaml and pyyaml3 libraries (rebooted computer for good measure), and then reinstalled **only** qgis-dev 2.99 first. Checked to make sure that vector processing libraries was working in qgis 2.99 before I reinstalled the old 2.18 version again. Now things work as they should :)